# Minimum functionality for an iOS app to be approved in App store

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I have an app requirement. App's functionality is to launch another app thats already installed in the device using a custom url scheme for the installed app. IF this is the only functionality of the application will Apple approve this in the App store?

Comment: No matter if it would get approved or not, what good would an app like this do?

Comment: Than what is the need to create app like this just with this functionality ??!! Its not the good idea.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, that's not enough functionality to get approved.